# zone delegation in Bind

Tags: linux, dns, bind

I have a lot of zones defined in my DNS server. I need to delegate one particular zone to a foreign DNS server and I don't have access to my domain-registrar control panel, currently.
Is there a way in Bind to delegate the resolution of a whole zone to another DNS server?

I thought it was possible to just name the foreign server `ns1.delegatenameserver.com` in the zone file but it's not working.

```
$TTL 3600
@               IN SOA ns1.delegatednameserver.com. hostmaster.ariel.org. (
                        2013120904      ;serial
                        3600            ;refresh
                        360             ;retry
                        86400           ;expire
                        3600            ;minimum
                )

                IN NS           ns1.delegatednameserver.com.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your question how far along you are, but to delegate a subdomain you have to have control over its parent domain.

So, if you control `example.com` and want to delegate `sub.example.com` to another DNS, you have to do:

In example.com's zone file

```
## this is the "glue" record
sub.example.com. IN NS ns1.sub.example.com.
ns1.sub.example.com. IN A 123.123.123.123 ;; IP address of the foreign DNS server to which you're delegating
```

In the foreign DNS server:

```
## you must have configured the sub.example.com zone
@           IN SOA ns1.sub.example.com. hostmaster.sub.example.com. (
                    2016060700      ;serial
                    3600            ;refresh
                    360             ;retry
                    86400           ;expire
                    3600            ;minimum
            )

                     IN NS  ns1.sub.example.com.
ns1.sub.example.com. IN A   123.123.123.123

www                  IN A   121.121.121.121
;; etc
```

Note that you can only properly delegate a subdomain, and to achieve it you must control its upper-level domain.

If you don't have control over the upper-level domain, you can still transfer load/responsibility over a domain by other means.

Let's say you control `example.com` at `ns1.example.com` (delegator) and want to delegate to `ns3.example.com` (delegatee).

**1. add extra NS records to the zone file in `ns1.example.com` and set up a master/slave relationship**

Your delegator nameserver will still get requests, but some clients will hit the delegatee.
You must set up `example.com` as a slave zone in `ns3.example.com` with master `ns1.example.com` for this to work. You will still have control of `example.com` in your delegator nameserver.

**2. forward the zone to `ns3.example.com`**

You can forward every request you receive to `example.com` by configuring:

```
zone "example.com" IN { type forward; forwarders { 122.122.122.122; }; }; // ns3.example.com
```

You will still receive every request for `example.com` on your delegator nameserver, which will then send the request forward but control of the zone contents will be entirely under control of the delegatee `ns3.example.com`.

In the delegated nameserver, `example.com` must be configured as a master zone.

**3. ns1.example.com as slave**

You can set up `example.com` as a slave zone in `ns1.example.com` with master `ns3.example.com`.

This is similar to option 2 above, with the difference that `ns3.example.com` won't be receiving any DNS requests from the world, only zone transfer requests from `ns1.example.com`.
`ns1.example.com` also keeps a cached copy of the zone and will still answer queries if `ns3.example.com` goes down.

Answer (score 0):

The address of the name server is missing in this zone declaration.

Add the following to your declaration file.

```
ns1  IN A  ip.of.delgated.server
```